# Qt5 - Linux app deployment - can you dynamically use dependencies?

Tags: qt5

I have a Linux Qt 5 application I'm trying to deploy on other Linux systems. I'm using VirtualBox machines to develop and test (both 32 bit). My application runs with the dependencies on the developer machine, but not on a non-developer test machine (where Qt 5 is not installed). I have a script which identifies the dependencies identified by using the ldd command. Are there any dependencies not listed by the ldd command? I'm trying to dynamically link the dependencies. Is that possible? Or do I have to configure and build from the source code with the static option? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` = "64" ]
    then
        LIBS=./data/libs_64
        BIN=./data/bin/Lottery_64
    else
        LIBS=./data/libs_32
        BIN=./data/bin/Lottery_32
    fi

    # Run your app
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBS:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    $BIN $@
```

The dependencies are in libs_32. I have the platforms folder in the binary directory. Do I need any other plugins?

Here's the dependencies I'm using:

```
linux-gate.so.1 
libQt5Widgets.so.5 
libQt5Gui.so.5 
libQt5Core.so.5
libstdc++.so.6 
libgcc_s.so.1 
libc.so.6 
libpthread.so.0 
libgobject-2.0.so.0 
libglib-2.0.so.0
libX11.so.6 
libm.so.6 
libGL.so.1 
libicui18n.so.49 
libicuuc.so.49 
libdl.so.2
libgthread-2.0.so.0 
librt.so.1 
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 
libffi.so.6 
libpcre.so.3 
libxcb.so.1 
libglapi.so.0 
libXext.so.6 
libXdamage.so.1 
libXfixes.so.3 
libX11-xcb.so.1
libxcb-glx.so.0 
libXxf86vm.so.1
libdrm.so.2 
libicudata.so.49 
libXau.so.6 
libXdmcp.so.6
```

Are there any dependencies I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
>Or do I have to configure and build from the source code with the static option?
```

This is the way I would go. You need to re-build your QT adding -static t "configure" and you have not so much problem with deploy than. 
BTW: if you want to do it time-saving use switches "-nomake demos -nomake examples".

Be aware about the licence's problem by linking statically :(